# Class does not exist antonioribeiro/tracker

Tags: laravel-5.6

Hello guys I am using antonioribeiro/tracker from github and followed all the instructions everything went smooth but when I tried to access the stats panel it returns an error that

> class admin does not exists.

In the tracker.php, I found the error is from this line `'authentication_ioc_binding' => ['auth','admin']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating admin class but it did not fix the issue. I was confused with the documentation of the package. The code that I followed is for multiple authentication driver. So I used the default setting `authentication_ioc_binding => ['auth']` this solves the issue.

Comment: Now its showing authentication required. What to do?

Comment: You need to be authenticated first because authentication_ioc_binding values are your middlewares. Run php artisan make:auth to enable the auth middleware built in in Laravel.